# magento2 add simple product to order

Tags: magento2, orders, cart, event-observer, quote

I want add surprise functionality so when custom try to place an order, one simple product will get automatically added to their cart. I want to add that item after customer click on place order button.  To achieve that, I have used Observer checkout_submit_before and loading the quote id.

Here is my observer code.  I have loaded the qupte and added my surprise item to the quote. Issue is, it's adding item in **quote_item** table but it's not adding item into order.  In quote_item table I can see the new SKU for that particular Quote. I'm missing something here.  Can anyone please guide me?  I also tried to convert Quote Item to Order item using ToOrderItem class but no luck. I tried so many things for so many hours but still at the same point.

```
<?php

  namespace Jackson\Surprise\Observer;

  use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface; 
  use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
  use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as ToOrderItemConverter;

class Surprise implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * @var CartRepositoryInterface
 */
public $cartRepository;

private $productRepository;
private  $quote;

/**
 * @var ToOrderItemConverter
 */
protected $quoteItemToOrderItem;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
    ToOrderItemConverter $quoteItemToOrderItem,
    QuoteFactory $quote
){
    $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
    $this->quote = $quote;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->quoteItemToOrderItem = $quoteItemToOrderItem;
}
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylogfile.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $logger->info("=========start1============");
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $quoteId = $order->getEntityId();
    $logger->info($quoteId);
    if ($quoteId) {
        $logger->info("=========start2============");

        $sku = 'LYLP';
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
         $cart = $this->quote->create()->loadActive($quoteId);

        $cart->addProduct($product, $this->makeAddRequest($product, $sku, 1));
        $cart->setItemsCount($cart->getItemsCount() + 1);
        $cart->setItemsQty((float)$cart->getItemsQty() + 1);
        $orderItems = [];
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
            $itemId = $quoteItem->getId();

            if (!empty($orderItems[$itemId])) {
                continue;
            }

            $parentItemId = $quoteItem->getParentItemId();
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $parentItem */
            if ($parentItemId && !isset($orderItems[$parentItemId])) {
                $orderItems[$parentItemId] = $this->quoteItemToOrderItem->convert(
                    $quoteItem->getParentItem(),
                    ['parent_item' => null]
                );
            }
            $parentItem = isset($orderItems[$parentItemId]) ? $orderItems[$parentItemId] : null;
            $orderItems[$itemId] = $this->quoteItemToOrderItem->convert($quoteItem, ['parent_item' => $parentItem]);
        }


        $cart->collectTotals();
        $cart->save();


        /*            $cart = $this->cartRepository->getActiveForCustomer(8);

                    $cart->addProduct($product, 1);
                    //   $quote->addProduct($product, $this->makeAddRequest($product, $sku, 1));
                    $cart->collectTotals();
                    $this->cartRepository->save($cart);
                    //$cart->save();
        $quote = $this->cartRepository->getForCustomer(8);
        $quote->addProduct($product, 1);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->save($quote);*/

        $logger->info("=========save2============");
    }


}

private function makeAddRequest(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $sku = null, $qty = 1)
{
    $data = [
        'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
        'qty' => $qty
    ];



    $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $request->setData($data);

    return $request;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use observer `sales_order_place_before` so that you can add the product before saving the order. `checkout_submit_before` should also work, but I am not sure why it is not working for your.

in `etc/events.xml` add this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
        <observer instance="Jackson\Surprise\Observer\Frontend\Sales\OrderPlaceBefore" name="jackson_surprise_observer_frontend_sales_orderplacebefore_sales_order_place_before"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Now your observer `Jackson\Surprise\Observer\Frontend\Sales\OrderPlaceBefore` code will be this:

```
<?php
namespace Jackson\Surprise\Observer\Frontend\Sales;

class OrderPlaceBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $quoteRepository;
    protected $toOrderItem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $toOrderItem
    ){
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->toOrderItem = $toOrderItem;
    }
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
        $sku = "my_sky";
        $this->makeAddRequest($order, $quote, $sku);
    }

    private function makeAddRequest($order, $quote, $sku, $qty = 1)
    {
        try {
            $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
            return;
        }

        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        $stockqty = $stockItem->getQty();

        if ($stockqty > $qty) {
            $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $product->getId(), //product Id
                'qty' => $qty //quantity of product
            );

            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $request->setData($params);
            $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
            $quote->collectTotals();
            //$this->_cart->save();

            foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                if ($product->getId() == $item->getProduct()->getId()) {
                    /**
                     * collect item price
                     */
                    $item->save();
                    $existData = $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getId());
                    $orderItem = $this->toOrderItem->convert($item);

                    if ($existData) {
                        $existData->addData($orderItem->getData());
                    } else {
                        /**
                         * add new product to
                         */
                        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                            $item->setParentItem(
                                $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId())
                            );
                        }
                        $order->addItem($orderItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**#Edited**

I think in your code this part is missing:

```
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            if ($product->getId() == $item->getProduct()->getId()) {
                /**
                 * collect item price
                 */
                $item->save();
                $existData = $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getId());
                $orderItem = $this->toOrderItem->convert($item);

                if ($existData) {
                    $existData->addData($orderItem->getData());
                } else {
                    /**
                     * add new product to
                     */
                    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                        $item->setParentItem(
                            $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId())
                        );
                    }
                    $order->addItem($orderItem);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: CollectTotals is already there.  even without form key Item is getting added in quote but not in order.  There should be some code to pass to order.  May be we need to reload quote?

Comment: I have done similar task before, I can update my answer, but you need to change your observer and coding style for the. I have working code

Comment: post it as answer please.

Comment: Answer updated, please check

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?